# Como llenar un listview con datos de una base sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Buenas tardes resulta que tengo un boton de ingresar datos a la bd y funciona perfectamente, un campo de texto llamado codigo con un listview llamado lista1, la idea es traer los datos segun el codigo y llenar el listviwe dando click a un boton pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que lo que necesitas es algo como esto:

```
 public void cargalist(){
        ArrayList <String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db=sql.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor fila= db.rawQuery("select * from items",null);
        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
             do{
                items.add("Clave: "+fila.getString(0)+"\n"+
                "Cantidad: "+fila.getString(1)+"\n"+"Nombre: "+fila.getString(2));
             }while (fila.moveToNext());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        listait.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
```

lo unico que haces es la consulta se lo que deseas, y ponerlo dentro de un arrayadapter como se muestra en el ejemplo